# string() does what I hoped strconv.Itoa() would do

Tags: go, ascii

I have a short program that converts a few binary numbers into their ASCII equivalents.  I tried translating this into [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) today and found that `strconv.Itoa()` doesn't work as I expected.

```
// translate Computer History Museum t-shirt
// http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/qksAAOSwaB5XjsI1/s-l300.jpg

package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
)

func main() {
        var binaryStrings [3]string
        binaryStrings = [3]string{"01000011","01001000","01001101"}

        for _,bin := range binaryStrings {
                if decimal, err := strconv.ParseInt(bin, 2, 64); err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                } else {
                        letter := strconv.Itoa(int(decimal))
                        fmt.Println(bin, decimal, letter, string(decimal))
                }
        }
}
```

which outputs

```
$ go run chm-tshirt.go 
01000011 67 67 C
01001000 72 72 H
01001101 77 77 M
```

So it seems like `string()` is doing what I thought `strconv.Itoa()` would do.  I was expecting the third column to show what I get in the fourth column.  Is this a bug or what am I missing?

Comment: `strconv.Itoa` changes `72` to `"72"`. Runes are already integers, so `string(72)` gives you the rune associated with it (`'H'`)

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes.  I read the docs and googled this for an hour.

Comment: Go's `strconv.Itoa` function is based on `itoa` in the [C standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/). The behavior is well-documented for both Go and C. I did not vote, but since your question title is phrased as a statement and you end by asking whether a _standard library function_ has an obvious bug, I am not surprised by the downvotes.

Comment: I find this question useful. For a beginner, without strong background in `C`, it is not very intuitive that `Itoa()` functions parses the integer to string. It is very tempting to use `string()` which is analogous to `toString()` method in other languages and get confused about the results. +1

Comment: Even with C/C++ experience this was a detail that I had forgotten with the passage of time.  Thanks for your vote.

Comment: Upvoted because the question draws attention to the behaviour of `string(intValue)` which is likely to be surprising to people with experience in other programming languages. I presumed `string(123)` would yield the result `"123"`, but it actually returns `"{"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`strconv.Itoa`](https://godoc.org/strconv#Itoa) formats an integer as a decimal string. Example: `strconv.Itoa(65)` and `strconv.Itoa('A')` return the string `"65"`.

[`string(intValue)`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.  Example: `string('A')` and `string(65)` evaluate to the string `"A"`.

Experience has shown that many people erroneously expect `string(intValue)` to return the decimal representation of the integer value. Because this expectation is so common, the Go 1.15 version of `go vet`  warns about `string(intValue)` conversions when the type of the integer value is not `rune` or `byte` (read details [here](https://golang.org/doc/go1.15#vet)).

Comment: Guy from JS like me can get easily trapped with string(). Thank you for clarification.