# Why is string(float64) return _ in 1.13 and error in 1.16

Tags: go

Consider the following code

```
c := 90
d := 101
a := int64( (float64(c) / float64(d)) * 100)
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(string(a))
```

Here is 1.16 [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PAgx3z9C7Fi)

which returns

```
./prog.go:13:21: conversion from int64 to string yields a string of one rune, not a string of digits (did you mean fmt.Sprint(x)?)
```

and in 1.13 in my local it return `_`

neither is what I expected which is `89`

Can someone point me a hint on why is this the behavior, and what is the recommended way of casting int64 to string

Comment: This message `./prog.go:12:21: conversion from int64 to string ...` (on the playground) is not the program output, it is a warning message from go vet telling you that you likely have a bug in your code.  The program then runs and outputs `89` and `Y`.  Read the warning message fully if you're wondering about converting int64 to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Go Specification section on conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) defines conversion *to* `string`, from a signed or unsigned integer type, as producing a string containing **the UTF-8 representation of** a single Unicode rune as specified by the integer's value.  Hence, as [Hymns For Disco notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66415628/why-is-stringfloat64-return-in-1-13-and-error-in-1-16#comment117415297_66415628), `string(89)` first converts 89 to the corresponding Unicode rune, which is simply LATIN UPPERCASE LETTER Y, then encodes this rune in UTF-8, producing the string `"Y"`.  (To get `_` you need `string(95)`.)

As this documentation similarly notes, `string(0xf8)` will produce `"ø"` which is the same as `"\xc3\xb8"`, and `string(0x6535)` produces `"日"` or `"\xe6\x97\xa5"`.

Many Go users are surprised by this, expecting `string(89)` to produce `"89"`.  In fact, you need `strconv.Itoa` or `fmt.Sprint` or similar to do this: see also [string() does what I hoped strconv.Itoa() would do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39235626/1256452).  [Rob Pike himself has suggested that `string(integer_value)` be deleted from Go 2.](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3939)  As Cerise Limón notes in the linked question, that's why `go vet` now points out this common error.